# Are instructions available for cross-compiling gtkmm (v3 specifically) windows libraries/apps on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, gtkmm

Currently I am writing a gtkmm3 GUI in netbeans and using a linux dev server to compile linux binaries as I go. As I really want my final program to be cross platform, I set up a dev server specifically for compiling windows apps in linux. I am using the custom repo listed here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64-archlinux but I am having trouble using pkg-config. I have tried all combinations I can think of (pkg-config mingw-w64-gtkmm3, pkg-config gtkmm-3.0, pkg-config mingw-w64-gtkmm-3.0, etc.) but all of them give me an error liks this:

```
Package mingw-w64-gtkmm3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mingw-w64-gtkmm3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mingw-w64-gtkmm3' found
```

I am new to doing cross-compiling, so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after poking around in the /usr directory for awhile. I advise anyone else struggling with this problem to do the same to familiarize themselves with mingw-w64.

the pkg-config command for mingw-w64 on arch is:

i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs

However, in order to use the above command, one first needs to install the following package on arch: mingw-w64-pkg-config (from the repo linked in the question)